# How to clear a memory early in c#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

After finishing use the varible, can I clear the memory early before the GC do it?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite memory contents or you want the GC to collect the object, referenced by the variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear"? Do you mean "zero out the memory contents to try to prevent someone else from reading it after I'm done with it", or do you mean "release the memory so it can be used for other purposes and subsequent memory allocations"?

Comment: There's hardly *ever* a reason to do this. Can you explain *why* you think you need to clear the memory early before the GC?

Comment: Environment.Exit() works well.  If that's not suitable then just don't even considering doing this.

Comment: @Hans Passant Hah! That's great advice, I'll use that from now on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are specific resources that need to be released immediately, implement the `IDisposable` interface and call `Dispose()` (sometimes `Close()` on some objects, such as streams).

If you are looking to prevent passwords being retained in memory beyond their lifespan, `SecureString` supports this, though it is not simple to use.

Otherwise, you have no control over when the garbage collector runs or what it actually does. If you desperately need this kind of control, you need a lower level language.

Comment: +1 for not suggesting nulling objects and forcing GC. Also, never used `SecureString` before, so I've learnt something new today!

Comment: Technically you do have some control through the GC.Collect() method that can force a memory reclaim attempt. I do agree with GenericTypeTea's comment though and I gave you a +1 for the same reasons. :)

Comment: @daft It's more an abstraction rule than a reality. If you want, you can require certain allocations be on the stack or a particular heap, but the rule is that you don't care. As I said in my answer, if you *have to* care, the managed runtime is not suitable.

Comment: True Zooba and very well explained I think. +1.

Comment: from memory calling Dispose() doesn't automatically dispose right then - it simply marks for disposal - which will actually be done according to the GC's whim

Answer (score 8):

As @Hinek said, you should call `GC.Collect()`. However, it alone won't do the part if you want the memory to be cleared immediately. You should call :

```
   //Force garbage collection.
   GC.Collect();

   // Wait for all finalizers to complete before continuing.
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Answer (score 5):

Set it's value to null. Than GC will collect it(during next GC run), if no other references to this object found. But you cannot clear memory by your own (except for unmanaged resources).

Comment: And note that "clear" memory here is vague. When you release memory to GC, and when GC reclaims it, it might not be zeroed out but still retain its old memory contents. Ie. a password could still be left in the memory where the string used to be.

Comment: Setting a reference object to null will not clear it from memory. It merely marks it for deletion by the GC later, **not** immediately. All setting variables to null is good for is dirtying code unless there's a specific logical/code-related reason to set it to null.

Comment: @Generic "Marking" it for deletion is also slightly inaccurate, there's no mark. Rather, when GC analyzes memory graphs, it will find no references left for the object, and that's how it knows the object is eligible for collection.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea Setting variables to null can also help detect errors where it is used after it shouldn't be. Not everybody implements `ObjectDisposedException` in their classes.

Comment: @Zooba, see the last sentence of my first comment... **unless there's a specific logical/code-related reason to set it to null**. @Lasse - *Marking* is a perfectly acceptable word in this scenario, but if you want to discuss that further, take it to english.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this method:

```
public static void FlushMemory()
    {
        Process prs = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        try
        {
            prs.MinWorkingSet = (IntPtr)(300000);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

three way to use this method.

1 - after dispose managed object such as class ,....

2 - create timer with such 2000 intervals.

3 - create thread to call this method.

i suggest to you use this method in thread or timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the system to make a sweep and evaluate all objects and consider them for collection by calling `GC.Collect();`

If the objects are still referenced they will not be collected however.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your variable to `null` and run `GC.Collect()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.gc.collect(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: First of all, this is incomplete. Second, this is a really, really bad practice to get into. The point is you never have to do this in .NET.

Comment: First of all, this isn't incomplete, he doesn't say, he wants to wait until the memory is cleared. Second, of course the point of a GC is, that you don't have to care for clearing the memory. But he is asking for a solution to clear it manually, so this is a valid answer.

Comment: never and ever trust on GC.Collect without careful consideration:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Comment: @Cody, you should consider calling GC.Collect() if some non-recurring event has just happened and this event is highly likely to have caused a lot of old objects to die.

Comment: @RoadWarrior: *Why?* Do you have some source for that guideline? Maybe more of an explanation to offer? Garbage collection is an expensive process. It should only run when it needs to, generally when the application is *idle* so that it doesn't interfere with what the user is doing. There's absolutely nothing to gain by running it early. Garbage collection doesn't matter unless you're running low on memory.

Comment: @Cody, my source and the full explanation is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx. This is a situation where the GC's tendency to try to predict the future based on the past is likely to be unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mayank said use both

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Since the program will not continue and increase memory usage until free the previous used memory.